# Only load URLs in Safari from UIWebView after initial load?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, safari, youtube

I've been trying for the last week to figure out how to detect when Javascript is loading on a webpage and then jump out from the UIWebView into Safari.

I'm currently using this code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

on the URL http://m.youtube.com/

(Usually the line `if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {` works, but not with Javascript pages like YouTube, so I used `if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther) {` instead.

This works, but unfortunately jumps to Safari the first time the page is loaded. I only want subsequent pages to load in Safari.

Is there a way to detect the first time a page is loading and then stop it from opening in Safari, but allow subsequent requests to open in Safari? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

m

You can use below code, and let me know if any query u have...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

Comment: What is urlArr? I need to declare it before I can use it

Comment: But wouldn't that just open the url I put in urlArr? I want it to open the URL request that the UIWebView received.